# Codewars: Solving Kata - Highest and Lowest C++

Tags: c++

I was solving kata "Highest and Lowest" in codewars.com and got some issues while testing.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> splitString(string str) {
    stringstream ssin(str);
    long countSpaces = count(str.begin(), str.end(), " ") + 1;
    vector<string> numbers(countSpaces);
    int i = 0;
    while (ssin.good() && i < countSpaces + 1) {
        ssin >> numbers[i];
        ++i;
    }
    return numbers;
}

string highAndLow(const string& numbers) {
    int maxAndMin[] = { 0, 0 };
    vector<string> stringNums = splitString(numbers);
    int length = static_cast<int>(stringNums.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int number = stoi(stringNums[i]);
        if (number > maxAndMin[0]) maxAndMin[0] = number;
        if (number < maxAndMin[1]) maxAndMin[1] = number;
    }
    string result;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << maxAndMin[0] << " " << maxAndMin[1];
    result = ss.str();
    return result;
}
```

And issues:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/igloo/igloo_alt.h:10:
In file included from /usr/local/include/igloo/igloo_framework.h:12:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ios:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('char' and 'const char *')
        { return *__it == _M_value; }
                 ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:3188:6: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<char const[2]>::operator()<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >' requested here
        if (__pred(__first))
            ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4115:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__count_if<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<char const[2]> >' requested here
      return std::__count_if(__first, __last,
                  ^
./solution.cpp:10:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::count<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char *, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, char [2]>' requested here
    long countSpaces = count(str.begin(), str.end(), " ") + 1;
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Could you explain me please, what's wrong here?

Comment: `" "` is a null-terminated string literal of type `const char[1]`, however `' '` is a literal of type `char`. I think you wanted the second one in that case

Comment: @PeterT `const char[2]`, pardon my nitpicking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the error message, it contains all relevant information:

First, what the compiler does not like:

```
error: comparison between pointer and integer ('char' and 'const char *')
```

And then, which part of your code causes the issue:

```
long countSpaces = count(str.begin(), str.end(), " ") + 1;
```

Deep inside that count function, there is a loop comparing every element of str to the `" "`, you figure out the rest.